# How do I avoid deadloop if a user enters a char into a scanf looking for an interger?

Tags: c

I've been searching the web for a while now, without finding a satisfying answer. Now I'll try my luck here. So here it goes:

In my program I want a user to enter a number, via the terminal, for this I use scanf(). Rather simple, I know... and I've got that working. But I also want to make it "idiot-proof". Thus I'm trying to make sure that if the user enteres a character and not an interger, the program won't deadloop.
As it is now, if a character is entered the program will deadloop.

My code is:

```
long fs = 0;
printf("Enter the samplefrequency(in Hz) and press 'ENTER': ");
while(fs<=0)
{
    scanf(" %li", &fs);

    if(fs <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nThe samplefrequency must be above 0 Hz. Please enter again: ");
    }
}
```

This will keep printing the line in the if-statement.
How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to make user input from the console completely idiot-proof is this:

- [Do not use scanf](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).
- Read the input as a string, using `fgets`. Do not read it as an integer.
- Parse this string and see if it contains a valid number.
- Convert the string to an integer by using strtol().

Answer (score 0):

change it like this:

```
scanf(" %li", &fs);

while(fs <= 0)
{
    printf("\nThe samplefrequency must be above 0 Hz. Please enter again: ");
    scanf(" %li", &fs);
}
```

When you input a wrong number the loop will continue to prompt for a new number until it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that demonstrates how to use `fgets` with `sscanf` to solve the user input problem.

The function `getInputFromUser` displays `prompt1`, and then uses `fgets` to read a line of input from the user. (If `fgets` returns `NULL`, that indicates end-of-file from the user, and the program aborts.)

The function then uses `sscanf` to convert the input to a number. `sscanf` returns the number of successful conversions, so in this example a return value of `1` indicates that `sscanf` succeeded. (Additional range checking can be performed after the `sscanf` to make sure the number is acceptable.) If the `sscanf` fails, then the second prompt (`prompt2`) is displayed and the function tries again.

If and when the user gets around to entering a valid number, the function will return that value.

```
long getInputFromUser(char *prompt1, char *prompt2)
{
    long result = 0;
    char line[100];  

    printf("%s", prompt1);       
    for (;;)
    {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) 
        {
            // user hit the EOF key
            printf( "\nterminated by user...\n" );
            exit(1);
        }

        if (sscanf( line, "%ld", &result) == 1 && result > 0)
            break;

        printf("%s", prompt2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Call the function with the initial prompt, and the re-prompt for the user

```
long fs = getInputFromUser("Enter the samplefrequency(in Hz) and press 'ENTER': ",
                           "The samplefrequency must be above 0 Hz. Please enter again: ");
```